# Finding moment generating function of a discrete random variable (series)

Tags: probability, sequences-and-series

So the question is find the moment generation function for a random variable X with pmf $f_X(x)={{r+x-1} \choose x} p^r (1-p)^x ,x=0,1,2,\ldots, 0<p<1,\mbox{ and }r\in\mathbb{Z}^+$.

So it's a discrete random variable, and to find the $M_X(t)$ I take the expectation of $e^{xt}$, which gives me the series;

$\sum_{x=0}^\infty e^{xt}{{r+x-1} \choose x} p^r (1-p)^x$

I've been stuck on solving this summation for a while now. With a little manipulation I can get;

$$p^r\sum_{x=0}^\infty \frac{(r+x-1)!}{(r-1)!}\boxed{\frac{(e^t(1-p))^x}{x!}}$$
Where the boxed part of the equation is equivalent to $e^{e^t(1-p)}$, I'm at a bit of a loss about what to do with the previous term. In the text and class we've mostly dealt with these problems using the binomial distribution, but I don't see how it would be relevant to this problem since it's an infinite series.

Any help solving this series would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

You start off here with
$$
\DeclareMathOperator{\E}{\mathbb{E}}M_X(t)=\E[e^{tX}]=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{r+n-1}{n}p^r(1-p)^ne^{nt}.
$$
A helpful identity here is the following:
$$\tag{1}
(1-z)^{-a}=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{a+n-1}{n}z^n,\qquad \lvert z\rvert<1.
$$
$(1)$ is a consequence of the Binomial theorem: we have
$$
\begin{align*}
(1-z)^{-a}&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{-a}{n}(-z)^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{-a(-a-1)(-a-2)\cdots(-a-(n-1))}{n!}(-1)^nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^na(a+1)(a+2)\cdots+(a+n-1)}{n!}(-1)^nz^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(-1)^{2n}\binom{a+n-1}{n}z^n\\
&=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{a+n-1}{n}z^n.
\end{align*}
$$
(This is sometimes referred to as the *negative binomial theorem*, and is the reason that this type of random variable is actually called a *negative binomial distribution*.)

With $(1)$ in place, you can see
$$
M_X(t)=p^r\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\binom{r+n-1}{n}(e^t(1-p))^n=p^r(1-(1-p)e^t)^{-r}=\left(\frac{p}{1-(1-p)e^t}\right)^r.
$$
With the convention that we write $q=1-p$, this is sometimes written
$$
M_X(t)=\left(\frac{p}{1-qe^t}\right)^r.
$$

Also note that if you look at, for instance, the [Wikipedia article on the Negative Binomial Distribution](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Negative_binomial_distribution), you may find the roles of $p$ and $q$ reversed; this is because there are a couple of different ways to list the parameters of such a distribution.